# I can hear Kalista's voice globally on the map

Tags: league-of-legends

Everytime I play with/against a Kalista, I can hear her voice even though she is in the fog of war.

> Example: I play Darius top lane, enemy Kalista is bot lane, and around minute 1, I can hear Kalista saying something.

Is that a kind of bug ? Is it possible to disable it ?

Comment: Do you mean during the whole game, or just at the beginning (when she bonds with one of her teammates)? If the latter, that is supposed to be global to inform everyone in the game that Kalista has chosen a partner.

Comment: Oh well, that could explain a lot. I genuinely didn't know that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One of Kalista's [passive abilities](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Kalista/Abilities) allows her to bond with one of her teammates. This teammate enables her to do a little extra damage (through her W) and to ult (which throws the bonded teammate into a group of enemies and knocks them up).

In order to select which teammate to bond to, Kalista must use her spear item (which she automatically starts with) on someone. Since this choice cannot be changed after three minutes into the game, most Kalista players will simply choose whoever the support (occasionally jungler) is on the team. When she does so, she'll play an animation of her pulling a spear out of her back and throwing it at the feet of her new partner, who will "die" (not really) and then be bonded to her. During this mini-cutscene, Kalista will make a global announcement - usually something like "the oath has been taken". This is to notify enemies that Kalista has actually chosen a bonded partner. (This global notification is necessary because theoretically, Kalista could wait to bond with a partner until late in the game... though doing so puts her at a significant disadvantage so not many people do that. It also notifies them if, for example, she changes her partner after a jungle invade.)

Comment: Nice answer. But I thought you could buy another spear (for free) at the shop and bound someone else ?

Comment: You're stating that the bound ally cannot be changed anytime during the game. That's not entirely correct. Up to 3 minutes into the game you can re-buy the spear at no cost and chose a new soulbound ally. (Useless 99% of the time but still possible)

Comment: @Jutschge Had to look it up on the wiki, but you're right. I added that to my answer.

Comment: @Jutschge That's useful info. I've had it where a support goes afk or decides to leave lane forever because they're mad. In that case, it'd be useful to be able to change the bond.